# @InstallIn can only be used on @Module or @EntryPoint classes

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am new at the dependency injection on Android. I am using Dagger-Hilt and in AppModule class that I generated for the DB providers I got an error and the project doesn't compile.

The error is `@InstallIn can only be used on @Module or @EntryPoint classes`
This is my AppModule object. Where do I make mistake?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideAppDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext app: Context
) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    app,
    AppDatabase::class.java,
    "gelirkenal"
).build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideItemDao(db: AppDatabase) = db.itemDao()
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Still not found a solution?
My problem: @ InstallIn, can only be used with @ DefineComponent - annotated classes

Answer (score 24):

I set a import of Module as following:

`import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Module`

But the below is correct:

`import dagger.Module`

Answer (score 8):

Change the following imports:

```kotlin
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Module
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Binds
```

To =>

```kotlin
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Binds
```

Answer (score 6):

change `ApplicationComponent::class` to `SingletonComponent::class` and also you can find more hilt generated components by referring this [Hilt Generated Components](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#generated-components)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideAppDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext app: Context
) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    app,
    AppDatabase::class.java,
    "gelirkenal"
).build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideItemDao(db: AppDatabase) = db.itemDao()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you add `@InstallIn` annotation to not related class in your project.

Comment: I just added the `@InstallIn` annotation into AppModule. Also added `@HiltAndroidApp` to Application class, `@AndroidEntryPoint` to Activities and Fragments, `@ViewModelInject` to ViewModel constructor. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, import was incorrect

from:

```
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Module
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Provides
```

to:

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
```